# Variations of Case When Using CTE in SQL Server/R

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, database

I am trying to use a Case When in my final CTE statement. Right now, when I add the first statement `CASE WHEN`: `select *,CASE WHEN row_nbr = 1 AND Lagging = ProductTypeCode THEN OpenDate ELSE NULL END as NewOpen` it works and the code executes fine, but when I add:

`WHEN Lagging > ProductTypeCode THEN FullDate 
 WHEN Lagging < ProductTypeCode THEN FullDate 
 ELSE NULL END as NewOpen`

It doesnt execute. I've tried variations of `CASE WHEN` like `WHEN Lagging <> ProductType THEN FullDate` but still nothing.

```
q5<- sqlQuery(ch,paste(" 
;with CTE AS(
select 
   oz.acct_nbr as AccountID
  ,ac.prod_typ_cde as ProductTypeCode
  ,CASE WHEN ac.open_dte='0001-01-01' then null else ac.ACCT_OPEN_DTE END as OpenDate
  ,CASE WHEN ac.clos_dte = '0001-01-01' then null else ac.ACCT_CLOS_DTE  END as ClosedDate
  ,df.proc_date as FullDate
  ,row_nbr = row_number() over( partition by oz.acct_nbr order by oz.acct_nbr, df.proc_date asc )
  ,row_nbr2 = row_number() over( partition by oz.acct_nbr,ac.prod_typ_cde order by oz.acct_nbr, df.proc_date asc )
   FROM
   ODS.bic.TB_acct_m_fact df
   inner join
   ODS.bic.TB_acct_prod ac on df.DW_PROD_SERV_ID = ac.DW_PROD_SERV_ID
   left outer join
   ODS.bic.TB_ozz_acct_ard oz on df.proc_date = oz.proc_date and convert(bigint,left(ac.acct_grp_nbr,11)) = convert(bigint,oz.acct_nbr)
   WHERE
   ac.dp_cat_code  IN  ( 'N', 'M' )),
CTE1 AS(
select *
   ,lag(ProductTypeCode)over(partition by AccountID order by FullDate asc ) as Lagging
   ,LEAD (ProductTypeCode)over(partition by AccountID order by FullDate asc  ) as Leading
FROM CTE)
select *
   ,CASE 
       WHEN row_nbr = 1 AND Lagging = ProductTypeCode THEN OpenDate  
       WHEN Lagging > ProductTypeCode THEN FullDate 
       WHEN Lagging < ProductTypeCode THEN FullDate 
       ELSE NULL END as NewOpen
FROM CTE1;"))
```

Comment: You need to better explain what "It doesn't work" means.

Comment: Since you basically get only two values as result, OpenDate or FullDate, why don't you use an IIF() statement ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Is ```FullDate``` the same type as ```OpenDate```?

Comment: Yes they are both the same type

Comment: You should add some tables and information. What do you mean by does not execute - are any error messages available? And after looking at it, it seems like there are some simplifications available but it's difficult to say without a small reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the equivalent of `NewOpen`:

```
SELECT 
   oz.acct_nbr as AccountID
  , ac.prod_typ_cde as ProductTypeCode
  , CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY oz.acct_nbr ORDER BY df.proc_date asc) = 1 THEN df.proc_date END as NewOpen
 
FROM   ODS.bic.TB_acct_m_fact df
 INNER JOIN ODS.bic.TB_acct_prod ac             ON df.DW_PROD_SERV_ID = ac.DW_PROD_SERV_ID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ODS.bic.TB_ozz_acct_ard oz     ON df.proc_date = oz.proc_date 
                                                 AND convert(bigint,left(ac.acct_grp_nbr,11)) = convert(bigint,oz.acct_nbr)
   
WHERE ac.dp_cat_code  IN  ( 'N', 'M' )
```

### Where did the CASE WHEN statement go?

CTEs can be useful but it is easy to loose track of the original data. `CTE1 lagging` would evaluate to `NULL` when `row_nbr = 1` because the default return for `LAG()` outside of the partition is `NULL`. Therefore, we know that the first part of the *CASE WHEN* will always evaluate to false because `NULL <> ProductTypeCode`.

Then, we also know that you are only interested in returning `FullDate` is when `LAGGING <> ProductTypeCode`. The only time that would be true is when `row_nbr = 1` but unfortunately, we have a similar problem as before - `NULL <> ProductTypeCode` does not evaluate to true.

Comment: This is a great explanation and solution thank you!